# Access data of another reducer when dispatching an action?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, reducers, ngrx-store

Inside my angular app i have the following reducer tree defined:

```
export interface State {
    user: fromUser.State;
    logs: fromLogs.State;
    platforms: fromPlatforms.State;
    languages: fromLanguages.State;
    apps: fromApps.State;
    news: fromNews.State;
}
```

The main items here are the user and logs reducer. Inside the user reducer I have the data of the signed in user with the field `userData`. Next, I have the log reducer that stores an action to add a log:

```
export class RequestLogsAdd implements Action {
    readonly type = LogsActionTypes.REQUEST_LOGS_CHANGE;
    constructor(public textTag: string, public actionType: string, public tags: string[], public data: any) { }
}
```

The constructor has the parameters required to add a log.When this action is dispatched, it calls the following reducer:

```
case LogsActionTypes.REQUEST_LOGS_CHANGE:
        return {
            ...state,
            isLoading: true,
            logToAdd: {
                textTag: actions.textTag,
                type: actions.type,
                user: --,
                date: new Date(),
                tags: actions.tags,
                data: actions.data
            }
        };
```

Inside the field user theres an "--". That's because I'm uncertain on how can i retrieve the user reducer in here. Is there a way to get it?

At first I was thinking of adding the user as one of the parameters inside the constructor but I'd like to get it from the reducer so I dont have to get the user everywhere I use the log.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe the reducer which is having user detail and u can pass this user to the action which is calling this reducer.

Comment: That's exactly what im trying to avoid. I'm trying to get the data from the reducer so that i dont have to subscribe to the user everywhere i want to send a log.

Comment: Are you using epic as a middleware

Comment: No, Im'm using the ngrx library inside Angular.